# Ensuring different constructors have the same behaviour in Java

Tags: java, constructor

I was at an interview last week and one of the questions in the programming test was: "How can you ensure that different constructors in a class have the same behaviour in Java?". I wasn't and still am not sure about what "have the same behaviour" means. The answer I gave was:

```
    

    (new MyObject(...)).equals(new MyObject(...));
    (new MyObject(...)).hashCode == (new MyObject(...)).hashCode();
```

Here, in each line, the first MyObject(...) refers to one constructor and the second to the other.

What do you think the questions was actually asking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't consider your answer correct. You are only proving that two objects are equal (BTW if objects are equal, they *must* have the same `hashCode()`, the second comparison is redundant).

I think the correct solution is to have a single *primary* constructor and delegate all other constructors to it by calling `this(...)`. If all non-primary constructors are as short as possible, chances are they will all behave the same way because they all delegate to the same code.

And of course: unit-testing might have been the correct answer as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But more exactly, what do you mean by "behave the same way"?

Comment: @Alex: and what was the interviewer meaning saying "*have the same behaviour*"? I can only guess, in my opinion it means - have *consistent* behavior, which can be proven when they all delegate to the same constructor.

Comment: Well, that's the thing, I got the question during the test, not during the interview, so there was no one to ask what it means (not even afterwards). There's one little thing that doesn't make sense to me in your explanation: surely all non-primary constructors can delegate to the primary constructor, but afterwards they can do other things as well, otherwise all of them would be one line long, calling only super(...) with appropriate paramters. So how can they have the same behaviour?

Comment: @Alex: they won't have the same behavior completely, but big part of them will. You have one primary constructor providing common logic/behavior and others that add minor functionality (setting extra fields, pre-parsing). Obviously if all constructors have *exact* same behavior, then why have them? But if primary constructor takes `int` and does a lot of processing and another one takes String and parses it before delegating to `int` version - they still have the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

i think it was related to the use of `this()`and `super()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how would you use super() in this scenario?

Comment: If you have multiple constructors you can call `this()` with different arguments, but eventually you need to call `super()` (implicit or explicitly) probably in only one of them, and have the rest "chained"

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define equals and hashcode

for instance (worst one!) consider the following implementation of `equals()`

```
return true;
```

and the `hashcode()`

```
return 1;
```

now it doesn't even matter what the state of object is!

Comment: Yes, you are right. I did realize that when I wrote my answer, but I just couldn't figure out what "behave in the same way" meant. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Answer (score 0):

In case the classes you refer to don't override the methods given, then still equals will be false, since they are two different object (their memory allocation details are different). The hash code won't work either.

I think that you can write a piece of code that traverses the classes using reflection, and checks for each field that it has the same value. At the end, the two instances differ only by fields (not methods since they are set in compilation time).

Goodluck on your next interview.

Comment: Surely one would have overriden equals() before using it the way I did.